# parseInt on (class=) "h310" renders NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an element like so

```
<span class='h310'>blah</span>
```

Now

```
console.log($(this).attr('class'));
```

renders

`"h310"`

but

```
console.log(parseInt($(this).attr('class')));
```

renders `NaN` instead of the very much needed `310`.

What am I missing here and how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

The `h` is indeed static, I merely added it because "310" is not a valid class name according to the HTML spec while "h310" is.

Comment: Yes, obviously it returns NaN as parseInt method won't work for last number from string....

Comment: According to specification of javascript: if string starts with a char (not a number) result of `parseInt` will be `NaN`.
You could remove first character from your string before parsing or use RegEx.

Comment: That's because `h310` is not a number. You do not want to parse it as an int, but instead filter out non-numeric characters then parse it as an int.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I believed parseInt stripped all non numeric chars from a string and returned the remainder as an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The h is static

In that case you can simply replace the "h" and convert the string to a number using the unary plus:

```
+$(this).attr('class').replace('h', '');
```

```
> 310
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cNdKA/).

Comment: Actually, I put the `h` in there myself only because a **class name may not start with a digit**. Although other solutions (especially using regexes) are more generic, for now I'll go with the simplest one that works, which is the `replace()`.

Comment: @C-link the comment was posted on a now-deleted answer. If you have enough rep, you can still view it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243345/parseint-on-class-h310-renders-nan/23243438#comment35563970_23243406

Comment: @RubenGeert in that case you may be better off using [data-* attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` method will not work here as the class contains the character "h".

Try this (with "h" is static)

```
<span id="sp1" class='h310'>blah</span>

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#sp1').attr('class'));
    alert(parseInt($('#sp1').attr('class').replace('h', ''),10));
});
```

For a general solutions use regex.

```
console.log(parseInt($('#sp1').attr('class').match(/\d+/),10));
```

Live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qrmvu/)

Comment: radix should always be provided

Comment: parseInt has a second parameter (the radix) which should always be provided to avoid ambiguities ... otherwise a string like "016" would lead to the number `14` which might be unexpected and unwanted

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the number part of the string first. parseInt will only extract it automatically if there is no non-numeric character at the beginning of the string

```
var numberpart = $(this).attr('class').substring(1);
console.log(parseInt(numberpart, 10));  // make sure to provide the radix 10 for decimal numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obviously it returns NaN as parseInt method won't work for last number from string but if you have `310h` then it could be parsed with parseInt:

So, use regular expression here:

```
console.log(parseInt($('span').attr('class').match(/\d+/),10));
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2D2X/1/)

As @James you can also use like this:

```
$(this).attr('class').replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g, '');
```

Comment: Please provide the radix

Comment: parseInt has a second parameter (the radix) which should always be provided to avoid ambiguities ... otherwise a string like "016" would lead to the number 14 which might be unexpected and unwanted

Comment: Yes, for this one simple example. But try it with "h031"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str= $('span').attr('class');
var thenum = str.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
console.log(thenum)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9JTSQ/9/)